# compiler doesn't know my include file

Tags: c++, compilation, include, g++

I'm compiling my project using g++ and a jamroot file (jamroot.jam). I don't know why it doesn't know my files even it include the right directory.

Here is the output:

```
"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -fPIC  -DLINUX  \
  -I"/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc" \
  -I"/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc/include/cppunit" \
  -I"/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc/include/cppunit/ui/qt" \
  -I"/usr/share/boost" -c -o "bin/build/gcc-4.6/debug/src/main.o" "src/main.cpp"

In file included from src/main.cpp:6:0:
/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc/UT_Instrument_Test.hpp:7:45: fatal error:
  cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h :  No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare:

Your command -

```
-I"/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc/include/cppunit"
```

The error message:

```
fatal error: cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h : No such file or directory
```

I.e., the "include root" is expected to be at `/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc/include`, not the "cppunit" subdirectory (which is apparently stated in the `#include` directive).

Alternatively, your `#include` statement is wrong, and shouldn't have `cppunit/` in front of `extensions/HelperMacros.h`.

Comment: thank you all for your answers it is really clearer now, it works

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one :

```
-I/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc/include/
```

The reason is that you include like this :

```
#include "cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h"
```

and the full path is

```
/home/oumaya/docs/UT_Cpp_Test/main/inc/include/cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h
```

therefore you should tell the compiled the relative path to `cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h`

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying the `[...]inc/include/cppunit` path for your input files, but refer to the header as `cunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h`  This means the compiler is expecting path relative to `[...]inc/include/cppunit` and ends up with `[...]inc/include/cppunit/cunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h`.  You only need to specify `[...]inc/include` for the include directories (or change the header path to `extensions/HelperMacros.h`)

Answer (score 1):

It simply can't find the file. You're trying to include `cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h` so go through all the `-I` include paths in your build output and see if they concatenate together to a valid path to that file. They won't as you're missing a directory.

Next step is to go through the cppunit installation and find your file:

```
find <cppunit root> -name HelperMacros.h
```

When you find one which ends with your `cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h` include, strip that bit off the end and use the first part of the path as an extra `-I` include path on your compile command.

Answer (score 1):

When running Ubuntu I found you can simply install the correct stuff with

For cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h or cppunit/BriefTestProgressListener.h:

```
sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev
```